# TWRP: Unable to mount storage; Internal Storage (0MB); Install process fails

Tags: android, lineageos

I've a phone with TWRP v2.8.6.0 with no OS installed. When I boot into recovery to install a new OS, TWRP can not mount the storage. Here is the complete log:

```
E: Unable to mount '/data'
E: Unable to recreate /data/media folder
Updating partition details...
E: Unable to mount '/system'
E: Unable to mount '/cache'
E: Unable to mount '/data'
...done
E: Unable to mount storage.
E: Unable to mount /data/media during GUI startup.
E: Unable to mount '/cache'
Full SELinux support is present.
E: Unable to mount '/cache'
E: Unable to mount '/cache'
E: Unable to mount /data/media/TWRP/.twrps when trying to read settings file
```

Also, I tried to format above partitions to `ext2/ext3/FAT`, then back to `ext4`. But `ext4` formatting fails every time. However I doing this process with `fastboot` was fine but it didn't solve the above problem.

With that said, the Internal Storage show 0 MB size and TWRP fails to install new LineageOS.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Note : This will wipe/format your Data portion and your data will be reset.

INSTRUCTIONS :

1. Reboot your device into TWRP Recovery.
2. Go to Wipe menu.
3. Go to Advance Wipe.
4. Select Data and go to Repair or Change File System.
5. Click Repair File System. (If not fix, go to step number 6)
6. Go to Change File System.
7. Select Ext2 and swipe to confirm.
8. Now change back to Ext4 and swipe to confirm.
9. Now go back and check if your portions can be mount or not from Mount menu.
10. If not fix, repair your Internal partition. (This may wipe your Internal storage).

OR Unlock your boot loader again

[Please refer this link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/how-to-fix-unable-to-mount-data-t3830897)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, these steps didn't work for me.